# How do you add property and text files to a JAR file via build.gradle

Tags: java, file, gradle, jar, properties

I am building a Java JAR file with gradle and need to add some property and text files in the repo, but including them doesn't work. I currently have as follows the inclusion of the transient dependencies:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'myJarName'
    version =  '1.0.0'

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        include '**/*.json'
        include '**/*.properties'
    }
}
```

Also tried this:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'myJarName'
    version =  '1.0.0'

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    from('src/main') {
        include '**/*.json'
        include '**/*.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working by reversing the order on the from conditions, need to state the .props and .json files first!